# Can my one-handed or hook-handed ex-pirate use Dervish Dance?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats

So I'm making a character for a pathfinder game and I'm wanting to give her [**Dervish Dance**](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/dervish-dance-combat), but there are a few questions I have about the feat.

First of all, Dervish Dance says, "You cannot use this feat if you are carrying a weapon or shield in your off hand". What if the character in question only has one hand? (Part of her backstory is she used to be a pirate and lost her hand.)

Second of all, what if she replaces her missing hand with [a hook](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-descriptions/hook-hand)? Does that count as "carrying a weapon in your off hand"?

Comment: To clarify: Most folks lawyer Dervish Dance in an effort to two-weapon fight despite the feat's restrictions. Is that the case here?

Answer (score 10):

## Here's the intent

I suspect most GMs would be perfectly fine with a character who had a hook employing the feat Dervish Dance were such a character *not* two-weapon fighting.

That said, in this [2010](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2kpxu?Dervish-DanceWeapon-Finess-Questions#1) thread Paizo creative director James Jacobs says that the feat

> Dervish Dance isn't supposed to reward tricky-thinking two-weapon fighters, after all. It's supposed to make fighting with a single weapon more attractive, so as soon as you start trying to game the system to get an off-hand attack, you're breaking the spirit of Dervish Dance and the feat should stop working.

Then designer Sean K. Reynolds follows up on this, saying

> Dervish Dance is also specifically intended to let you use a scimitar with the duelist prestige class, as many of the duelist's abilities require (1) no weapon or shield in the off-hand, and (2) your weapon has to be a piercing weapon.

So, yeah, if a character with the feat Dervish Dance in James Jacobs's or Sean K. Reynolds's campaign chopped off his hand, slapped a hook on the stump, then tried to go two-weapon fighting using a scimitar in the main hand and the hook in the off-hand, those GMs would probably tell that character *No*.

Answer (score 3):

Losing a hand in pathfinder sucks.  First of all, it disqualifies you from the majority of hand-slot magic items, as, while you still get a 'hands' slot, most items in that slot require a pair of gloves/gauntlets/etc to be worn, though there are some exceptions.

Fortunately for our aspiring dancer, lacking a hand and carrying something in it are not the same. Dervish Dance doesn't require a free hand (which would basically prevent her from using it), it just requires that she not have more than one hand carrying a weapon or shield (her primary hand has to be holding an appropriately sized scimitar, of course, but that's a separate requirement).  This means, as she *doesn't have an off hand* that she *always* meets this requirement.

A hook hand is a weapon, and a creature wielding such a weapon in their off hand cannot dervish dance.  Our lucky impoverished amputee doesn't have an off hand, however, and wields the hook with her stump.  It is treated as a secondary attack, also known as an off-hand attack, but she is *not* carrying it in her off hand.

Note that in certain philosophies of the body, an enemy could merely recover her severed hand and place a weapon or shield within it to strip her of the feat.  You may want to discuss with your GM if this would work and what you want to do about it.

Comment: Holy crap, this is a *extremely* literal interpretation of the raw hahaha

Comment: I think the restriction on off-hand held items is to prevent 2-weapon fighting/shields (flavourwise, those would get in the way of movement). I can't see a hook getting in the way the same way, and certainly not an item placed in the severed hand. Aside, is there a reason you don't want to regenerate the severed hand?

Comment: @GreySage seems like a good question for the asker.  I assume it's cause she's dirt poor and crippled and so can't afford a regeneration.